# Default parameter doesn't work

Tags: python

I got the following problem in Python code.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "cmd.py", line 16, in <module>
    func(b="{cmd} is entered ...") # Error here
File "cmd.py", line 5, in func
    exceptMsg = b.format(errStr=errStr, debugStr=debugStr)
KeyError: 'cmd'
```

The code:

```
import re

def func(errStr = "A string", b = "{errStr}\n{debugStr}"):
    debugStr = "Debug string"
    exceptMsg = b.format(errStr=errStr, debugStr=debugStr)
    raise ValueError(exceptMsg)

try:
    '''
    Case 1: If user invokes func() like below, error produced.
    Possible explanation: Paramter b of func() is looking keyword   
    'errStr' further down in func() body, but I am passing it keyword
    'cmd' instead. What to change to make the code work?
    '''
    #cmd = "A crazy string"             # Comment, make code pass 
    #func(b="{cmd} is entered ...")     # Error here

    # Case 2: If user invokes func() like below, OK.
    errStr = "A crazy string"
    func(b="{errStr} is entered")

except ValueError as e:
    err_msg_match = re.search('A string is entered:', e.message)
    print "Exception discovered and caught!"
```

1) If the function interface func() is preserved, what code to change?

2) If I must modify the function interface, how'd I go about making it a clean code change?

Comment: Output (continued):
----------------
$ python cmd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmd.py", line 16, in <module>
    func(b="{cmd} is entered ...")     # Error here
  File "cmd.py", line 5, in func
    exceptMsg = b.format(errStr=errStr, debugStr=debugStr)
KeyError: 'cmd'

$ python cmd.py
Exception discovered and caught!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please put that into your question, properly formatted.

Comment: Its probably best to add the output to the post itself, no?

Comment: Note that the variable `errStr` ("A crazy string") isn't used for formatting and its presence has no effect on anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b.format(errStr=errStr, debugStr=debugStr)` only passes `errStr` and `debugStr` to replace placeholders. If `b` contains any other placeholder variables it will fail.

You have:

```
b = "{cmd} is entered ..."
```

There is nothing to match `{cmd}`

If you wanted to pass `cmd` to `func`, you can do it with [keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python):

```
def func(errStr = "A string", b = "{errStr}\n{debugStr}", **kwargs):
    debugStr = "Debug string"
    exceptMsg = b.format(errStr=errStr, debugStr=debugStr, **kwargs)
    raise ValueError(exceptMsg)
```

And use as:

```
func(b="{cmd} is entered ...", cmd="A crazy string")
```